# Why does Chrome considers the prototype of an object whose reference type is Date as "Object {}", not "Date {}"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, prototype, console.log

The code is simple.

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.__proto__);
console.log(now.__proto__.__proto__);
console.log(now.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);
```

In the console of Chrome, the result is shown as the screenshot.

[image]

The result seems correct in the console of Node.js.

[image]

Why doesn't `now.\__proto\__` return `Date {}` in Chrome's console?

Comment: There's no spec for what console output should look like.

Comment: What versions of Chrome/Node are you using exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a rendering, for which there's no specification.

Node does more computation to return the name of the `constructor` of the object whenever possible.

If you want to see it in the source, it's a little tedious to read because there are many different cases but it's basically in the [`formatValue` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L301) which is called by `util.inspect`.